# Improve performance to load 3000 records with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, postgresql, heroku

I have a Rails app running on Heroku.
I have a route leading to a 'home" controller and a 'listings' action:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
   get 'listings', to: 'home#listings'

end
```

My listing action:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
    def listings
      render json: MultiJson.dump({listings:Listing.all})
    end

    ...
end
```

I have a Listings table containing 3000 records.
The schema for the Listings table:

```
  create_table "listings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id",                              null: false
    t.boolean  "deleted",              default: false, null: false
    t.string   "rent",                                 null: false
    t.string   "deposit",                              null: false
    t.string   "availability",                         null: false
    t.string   "min_duration",                         null: false
    t.string   "male_count",                           null: false
    t.string   "female_count",                         null: false
    t.string   "longitude",                            null: false
    t.string   "latitude",                             null: false
    t.string   "location"
    t.string   "comments"
    t.string   "photos"
    t.datetime "created_at",                           null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                           null: false
  end
```

When are run 'heroku logs' I see this:

```
Started GET "/listings.json" for 108.6.235.199 at 2015-07-06 14:08:02 +0000
Processing by HomeController#listings as JSON
  Parameters: {"home"=>{}}
  Listing Load (34.3ms)  SELECT "listings".* FROM "listings"
Completed 200 OK in 3717ms (Views: 0.3ms | ActiveRecord: 40.4ms)
```

Is it normal for it to take 3.7 seconds to load and render 3000 records via json? Is there a way to improve performance to the order of a 100 miliseconds? Why is it that ActiveRecord time is 40.ms and Views is 0.3ms but Completed is 3717ms? Would it be better to use MongoDB instead of Postgres to store and load up the records with speed?

Comment: You should first find out which layer adds the overhead. What happens when you run `explain analyze select * from listings` in your SQL client? What is the runtime reported for that? It measures the runtime of the query on the **server** side, excluding any network or front end overhead.

Comment: Try putting these 3k records HARDCODED in an array in your controller and see how much time it takes to render that. It is not a matter of db performance. 3k objects take time to render.

Comment: I'd like to suggest that you start using some kind of pagination on the server side. Why would you ever want to send that much data to the client in one go anyway?

Comment: @ xlembouras, I liked your suggest so I put in a dummy array of 3000 hashes and I received this: 'Completed 200 OK in 929ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)' This is almost 3 seconds less - so surely fetching from database is eating a lot of time.

Comment: @Frost, that an interesting point - but I would prefer to get all the data at once than have to make numerous API calls which is ultimately more time consuming. This will also make for better user experience as there is zero latency.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, do you know how to access SQL console on heroku? Would love to try this

Comment: As far as I know you can use any SQL client (e.g. `psql`) to connect to a Heroku database - but I have never used Heroku so I don't know how exactly that works.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is not fetching the records from the DB, as your log shows, it only spend 40ms in an AR process (3000 records is nothing for PG).  The issue is serializing 3k records.

I recommend using [ActiveModel::Serializer](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) to help optimize the process.

Comment: I thought so too - so I put in a dummy array of 3000 hashes and I received this: 'Completed 200 OK in 929ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)' This is almost 3 seconds less - so surely fetching from database is eating a lot of time. Only 40ms to make the SQL call, but still 3 seconds to load up all the objects in run time.

Comment: Yes, MultiJSON can serialize an array of hashes much faster that an ActiveRecord_Relation object.  Look at your log:  `Listing Load (34.3ms)  SELECT "listings".* FROM "listings"`  It only took 34.4ms to retrieve the records from the DB and other 4.1ms to return the Collection to the controller.  If you go into the Rails Console, you can see the bottleneck:  retrieve the Listings and set to a local variable, then run `Benchmark.measure { MultiJson.dump(listing: <local_variable>) }`

Comment: Thanks tagCincy, I did this but nothing is shown: 
2.2.1 :004?>   listings = Listing.all
2.2.1 :005 >   listings.count
 (6.8ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "listings"
 => 3005 
2.2.1 :006 > Benchmark.measure { MultiJson.dump(listing: listings }
2.2.1 :007?>

Comment: So what is the bottleneck then? Benchmark.measure is silent

Comment: showing a ton of output, but not to that particular command, perhaps we can go on chat and I can show you

Comment: `Benchmark.measure { MultiJson.dump(listing: listings }`  Forgot the closing parentheses on the dump function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82519/discussion-between-etayluz-and-tagcincy).

Answer (score 0):

I followed up on @tagCincy's post and learned that the fastest way to build a json of all records in a database table is to let the database (in this case Postgres) do all the heavy lifting and let Rails and Active Record take a rest. Postgress supports a method called 'row_to_json'

```
 render json: MultiJson.dump({listings:ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("select row_to_json(listings) from listings;")})
```

This leads to a 6x speed improvement in performance in this case going from 3717ms
to 644ms as seen above in the question and below. It's actually even better than that because in this example I'm pulling the listings AND users table - whereas in the question it was only the listings table I was fetching.

```
 >   Started GET "/listings.json?data=(%0A%20%20%20%20settings,%0A%20%20%20%20listings,%0A%20%20%20%20users%0A)" for 108.6.235.199 at 2015-07-07 05:39:15 +0000
 >   (31.5ms)  select row_to_json(users) from users;
 >     Processing by HomeController#listings as JSON
 >       Parameters: {"data"=>"(\n    settings,\n    listings,\n    users\n)", "home"=>{}}
 >        (121.9ms)  select row_to_json(listings) from listings;
 >     Completed 200 OK in 644ms (Views: 0.3ms | ActiveRecord: 153.3ms)
```